# How to make the main modal window in a Windows Form application?

Tags: winforms

I want to create a simple Windows form to stop the kids playing games. It should be a simple form with an alert "Virus Detected". I want the form to be a modal one, so that the kids cannot switch to other apps without closing the window first.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your goal; if you are trying to “stop the kids playing games” you can do that already in Windows by creating accounts for your kids, enabling [parental controls](https://news.microsoft.com/en-in/features/windows-10-parental-controls-feature/), then specifying the apps you want them to run. This has nothing to do with WinForms. If you have trouble “create a simple Windows form” then you need to [post what you have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what is going wrong. Doing that has nothing to do with parental controls.